# Multi-Store View based extension in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I've developed a custom news extension for Magento 1.9 according to MagentoStudy_News that is covered in Magento's official study guide for developers.

The store that I'm building on Magento is multilingual that means that I have 3 store views, each corresponding for each language.

When adding news item it's only adding for all store views, there's no selection box for selecting store views (Scope).

Does anyone have any tips on how to develop a custom extension that supports the scope of stores and store views? How should the table of the multi store view based extension? What about config?

Answer (score -1):

To develop such extension manually it is somehow complex and takes time. Instead of it, you can adapt module creator extension which can be used to develop such kind of extension. Following is link of such module creator. In this extension, there is an option of 'enable by store' which can provide store selection that you want. Before using it, I recommend to use its help which can be found in Help tab when you open this extension in back-end. It allows you to create EAV as well as Flat type entity.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-module-creator.html

Comment: Thanks for advice but I need real solution, not some 3rd party extension that develops extensions. I need to know the practice of development.